# Select Statement for more than 1 value of a column for condition

Tags: sql

I have Order table (OrderID,salemanID, ProductTypeID, month, year...) , Saleman table( salemanID,...), and ProductTypes table (ProductID, Product_type....).

I tried to have query select all the Order Number which has more than 1 Product Type and saleman on order.

Here is my query:

```
Select O.OrderID, S.SalemanName, P.Product_type, count(P.productID)
From Order O join Saleman s ON O.salemanID = s.salemanID
             join ProductTypes P ON O.ProductTypeID = P.ProductID
Where O.month= '01'
and   O.year='2014'
Group by O.OrderID, S.SalemanName, P.Product_type
Having count(P.productID)>1
```

The output is this:

```
+------------+-------+------------+
|Order Number|Saleman|Product Type|
+------------+-------+------------+
|1234        |Andrew |Tables      |
+------------+-------+------------+
|1234        |Scott  |Tables      |
+------------+-------+------------+
|4321        |Andrew |Chairs      |
+------------+-------+------------+
|4321        |John   |Chairs      |
+------------+-------+------------+
```

What I want is one Order with More than 1 Product Types like this

```
+------------+-------+------------+
|Order Number|Saleman|Product Type|
+------------+-------+------------+
|1234        |Andrews|Tables      |
+------------+-------+------------+
|1234        |Barton |Chair       |
+------------+-------+------------+
|4321        |Andrews|Beds        |
+------------+-------+------------+
|4321        |John   |Chairs      |
+------------+-------+------------+
|4321        |John   |Desks       |
+------------+-------+------------+
```

Please help, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps You.

```
SELECT  O.OrderID [Order Number], S.SalemanName [Saleman], P.Product_type [Product Type] --, Count(P.productID)
FROM    (
            SELECT  x.OrderID
            FROM    [Order] x
                    Inner Join ProductTypes PT On x.ProductTypeID = PT.ProductID
            WHERE   x.month= '01'
                    And x.year='2014'
            GROUP BY x.OrderID
            HAVING Count(PT.ProductID) > 1
        ) O
        Left Outer Join [Order] OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
        Left Outer Join Saleman S On OD.salemanID = S.salemanID
        Left Outer Join ProductTypes P On OD.ProductTypeID = P.ProductID
```

Comment: Somehow I think about Count(distinct ProductID)> 1 would work

Comment: I got it, just add the distinct in HAVING Count(distinct PT.ProductID) > 1, it works perfect.  Thank you Jade

Comment: Eventhough I got it, when I add sum(Product_price) in , it not correct -- much more than expected, I guess because the Order table was join twice

Comment: the Order table is not joined twice, the subquery is completely separated since it already collected all the OrderID.  And the result table is joined to Order table after subquery. When you added the sum(Product_price) it also depends where you places it, and the number of tables and rows being joined.

Comment: Thanks Jade, I got it.  You're right about the Order table is not joined twice, my mistake of getting wrong table for joining.